# AngularJS errorcallBack

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I'm having some difficulty with AngularJS.  Any constructive help is greatly appreciated.

This is the Angular code I'm working with

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.element = function(num){
        var element_id = num;//num;  
        $http.get("customers.php",{params:{"id":element_id}}).then(function (response) {
            $scope.myData = response.data;
        }
        ,function errorCallback(response){
            $scope.e=response.data;
            console.log(e);

        });

    };

});
```

And here is my php code I'm using.  All this does is return the 401 code.  The section works as I can return it in a console log.

```
        http_response_code(401);
        $message = http_response_code()." No data found";
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($message);
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>page2</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src = "javascript.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="input">

        <div ng-controller="customersCtrl">
            <h1>Click on the contact name for company and location</h1>
            <br>
            <button ng-click="element(0)">Bob</button>
            <button ng-click="element(1)">Jim</button>
            <button ng-click="element(2)">Kim</button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
                     {{x}}
                 </li>
            </ul>

            <div ng-show="error != null">
                <p>{{e.error}}</p>
            </div>


        </div>
        <a href="#fullList">View full list</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm having a problem displaying the 401 message in the HTML page.  What is a good way of doing this?  The code will return the message but only as a console log. I need it in a HTML page. I'm quite confused on this one as I've tried multiple ways and none of them are working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: your scope property is `e` not `error` that is used in view

Comment: I tried      <div ng-show="error != null">
                <p>{{error.e}}</p>
            </div>  but still couldn't get  it to work

Comment: look in your controller.... there is nothing like `$scope.error` ... only `$scope.e`

Answer (score 0):

Hey Man try that below:

```
$scope.e = '';
$scope.myData = [];

$scope.element = function(element_id){
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "customers.php?id=" + element_id,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(
        function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.myData = response.data;
            callback(response);
        },
        function errorCallback(response) {
            $scope.e = response.data;
            callback(response);
        }
    );
}
```

Check on browser the network, and if no work, plz upload the network with log to "customers.php"

Best Wishes